# How to mock a legacy function without resorting to dependency injection?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Given the following hypothetical legacy production code:

```
struct Foo
{
     Bar bar;
     bool baz()
     {
         return !bar.qux();
     }
};
```

How do I mock `bar.qux()` so that it returns `true` in one test and `false` in another test, without resorting to [dependency injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

I'm using [Google Test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Test) framework, but want to avoid adding so many interfaces for dependency injections. Too many interfaces for the purpose of testability tends to make the production code overly complex.

Comment: If you don't want to do it at runtime via dependency injection, then you can do it a link time by linking against an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can probably do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

// test/MockBarMonitorsAndControls.hpp
namespace test
{
    bool const Bar_qux_default_output = true;
    std::deque<bool> Bar_qux_outputs;
    std::vector<int> Bar_qux_arg0_inputs;
}

// production/Bar.hpp
struct Bar
{
    bool qux(int x);
};

// production/Bar.cpp
// bool Bar::qux(int x)
// {
//    return static_cast<bool>(x & 2);
// }

// test/Bar.cpp
bool Bar::qux(int x)
{
    test::Bar_qux_arg0_inputs.push_back(x);

    if (!test::Bar_qux_outputs.empty())
    {
        auto result = test::Bar_qux_outputs.front();
        test::Bar_qux_outputs.pop_front();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return test::Bar_qux_default_output;
    }
}

// production/Foo.hpp
struct Foo
{
    Bar bar;
    int x = 9;
    bool baz()
    {
        return !bar.qux(x);
    }

    void henry();
};

// test/BarTest.cpp
void TestBar1()
{
    test::Bar_qux_outputs.clear();
    test::Bar_qux_arg0_inputs.clear();

    test::Bar_qux_outputs.push_back(false);

    Foo foo;
    bool pass = true;

    auto result = foo.baz();
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST1_ERROR: expected true result" << std::endl;
        pass = false;
    }

    auto input = test::Bar_qux_arg0_inputs.front();
    if (input != 9)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST1_ERROR: expected arg0 to be 9 but got " << input << std::endl;
        pass = false;
    }

    if (pass)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST1 PASS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "TEST1 FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

// test/BarTest.cpp
void TestBar2()
{
    test::Bar_qux_outputs.clear();
    test::Bar_qux_arg0_inputs.clear();

    test::Bar_qux_outputs.push_back(true);

    Foo foo;
    foo.x = 21;

    bool pass = true;

    auto result = foo.baz();
    if (result)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST2_ERROR: expected false result" << std::endl;
        pass = false;
    }

    auto input = test::Bar_qux_arg0_inputs.front();
    if (input != 21)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST2_ERROR: expected arg0 to be 21 but got " << input << std::endl;
        pass = false;
    }

    if (pass)
    {
        std::cout << "TEST2 PASS" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "TEST2 FAIL" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TestBar1();
    TestBar2();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the sample output:

```
TEST1 PASS
TEST2 PASS
```